# Modal progress bar breaks my dropdown Menus bootstrap 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use progress bar in Modal, I add at the bottom of my html document the following:

```
   <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this works fine, but after adding this line my bootstrap dropdown menus stop working.

If I remove script src line above, my dropdown menus start working again but modal progress bar doesn't work. Modal is shown but no progress action is performed.

Progress bar works when in regular page. Only modal doesn't work.

When I use inspector of the dropdown menu. It doesn't perform any action when click.
No error in JS Console.

**HTML**

```
<td class="text-center">
 <div class="btn-group"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left">
 <li><a href="#" data-toggle="notify" data-message="Collecting device information" data-options="{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;success&quot;, &quot;pos&quot;:&quot;top-right&quot;}">Check device status</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Deploy Services</a>
  </li>                                       
  </ul>
  </div>
  </td>
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- My modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="getInfoModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Connecting to system...</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <div id="modalProgressBar" class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>                    
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#getInfoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    // Introduce delay and close after progress bar finish
    setTimeout(func, 3000);
        function func() {
            $('#getInfoModal').modal('hide');
            $('#devicestatus').parent().show();         
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
       $('#modalProgressBar').progressbar(100);
    }, 1000);

});
```

I use this example:
http://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/BmHcF

And same result in which drop down menus do not work after I add bootstrap.min.js.

All scripts included:

```
   <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Plugins-->
   <script src="vendor/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/filestyle/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Animo-->
   <script src="vendor/animo/animo.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Sparklines-->
   <script src="vendor/sparklines/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Slimscroll-->
   <script src="vendor/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Store + JSON-->
   <script src="vendor/store/store+json2.min.js"></script>
   <!-- ScreenFull-->
   <script src="vendor/screenfull/screenfull.min.js"></script>
   <!-- App Main-->

   <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>

   <!-- END Page Custom Script-->

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <!-- START Page Custom Script-->
   <script src="app/js/progressbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are all the external scripts you included?

Comment: The problem because of loading jquery 2 times and bootstrap min file 2 times hope so.

Comment: can reproduce the problem in a fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the line:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with the following lines:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure that jquery and bootstrap load before your other script which depends on it.